# The number of 3-colourings of rectangular grid

Tags: combinatorics

Given a $2\times 7$ grid (14 squares), I want to color its squares with 3 colors which no two adjacent (in vertical or horizontal) squares take the same color. How many options we have?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can choose any pair of distinct colours for the first column of two squares, which gives 6 options. Then each next column of squares can be coloured in three different ways, giving you a total of $6 \times 3^6 = 4374$ options total.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, let $P_n(c)$ be the number of colorings of the grid $2\times n$ with $c\geq 2$ colors. Then $P_1(c)=c\cdot(c-1)$ and for $n\geq 1$, 
$$P_{n+1}(c)=((c-1)+(c-2)^2)P_n(c)=(c^2-3c+3)P_n(c).$$
Can you say why the above recurrence holds?

What is the general formula for the number of colorings $P_n(c)$?

P.S. $P_n(c)$ is known as the [chromatic polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChromaticPolynomial.html) of the [ladder graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LadderGraph.html).

Comment: thanks!  So the general formula for the number of colorings                 
 P_n(c)=(c-1)*c*(c^2-3c+3)^(n-1)

Comment: Yes, that is correct!